# input value get hidden when ng-model is aded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a form with the angular values in it.

```
<tr ng-repeat="alldata in c.da">
                    <td>{{alldata.id}}</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{alldata.name}}"   /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{alldata.numbers}}" ng-model="contact.number" /></td>
                    <td><button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="alldata.contactid" value="{{alldata.id}}">Save</button></td>

                </tr>
```

when i add the `ng-model` the value is not displaying.
[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want `value` when you also have `ng-model`?

You can set the value via the model.

Comment: value for display the previous value and ng-model for submit the form and want to get in ng-submit

Comment: I'm afraid that's not how `ng-model` works. It will be kept always in sync. If you want something more complex, you need to code something (using two models, I suppose).